# How to determine the status of the job Async/Await

Tags: c#, asynchronous

i read this guide line from here http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

here i got few couple of code but not very clear to me.

**1)**

```
public async Task DoOperationsInParallelAsync()
{
  Task[] tasks = new Task[3];
  tasks[0] = DoOperation0();
  tasks[1] = DoOperation1();
  tasks[2] = DoOperation2();

  // At this point, all three tasks are running in parallel.

  // Now, we await them all.
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

in the above we are creating multiple task but suppose when all task will run parallel then  DoOperation2() may be finish first and DoOperation0() and at last DoOperation1() complete. if i want to show that message like DoOperation2() is completed in console windows then how could i do this. how could i detect that which task complete when multiple is running.

2) when we run any function with the help of **async/await** the does it run as background thread or foreground thread.

3)

```
public async Task<int> GetFirstToRespondAsync()
{
  // Call two web services; take the first response.
  Task<int>[] tasks = new[] { WebService1(), WebService2() };

  // Await for the first one to respond.
  Task<int> firstTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

  // Return the result.
  return await firstTask;
}
```

i do not understand why the person wrote **Await for the first one to respond.**

// Await for the first one to respond.
  Task firstTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

why first one...why not second one because two task are running here.

please guide me and drive out my confusion. thanks

Comment: I think some of your confusion is caused by language: first one to respond doesn't mean the first entry, it means whichever one that responds first will be the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because it's a console app, you need to wait for the task to finish.  Here's an example of how to return a string from a task:

   ```
   class WhenAny
   {
       public static async Task<string> GetFirstToRespondAsync()
       {
           // Call two web services; take the first response.
           Task<string>[] tasks = new[] { Task1(), Task2() };

           // Await for the first one to respond.
           Task<string> firstTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

           // Return the result.
           return firstTask.Result;
       }

       private static async Task<string> Task1()
       {
           await Task.Delay(3000);
           return "Task1";
       }

       private static async Task<string> Task2()
       {
           await Task.Delay(1000);
           return "Task2";
       }
   }
   ```

   Call that from the Main function as follows:

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var t = WhenAny.GetFirstToRespondAsync();
       t.ContinueWith((taskName) =>
           {
               string result = taskName.Result;
               Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
           });

       t.Wait();
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
   ```

   That should return the task that completes first, and you can access that information from the `Task.Result`
2. Awaiting a method does not, in itself, create an additional thread.  What it does is create a callback to avoid blocking the current thread (typically this is used to not block the UI thread).
3. `WhenAny` returns when the earliest completed operation returns.  That doesn't mean the first in the list that you provide.  So, the code above will always show 1000, even though it's the second task.

For completeness, here's the same thing with WhenAll:

```
class WhenAll
{

    public static async Task<string[]> WaitForAllAsync()
    {
        // Call two web services; take the first response.
        Task<string>[] tasks = new[] { Task1(), Task2(), Task3() };

        // Wait for a tasks
        string[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        // Return the result.
        return results;
    }

    private static async Task<string> Task1()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        return "Task1";
    }

    private static async Task<string> Task2()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return "Task2";
    }

    private static async Task<string> Task3()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        return "Task3";
    }

}
```

And to call it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var t = WhenAll.WaitForAllAsync();
     t.ContinueWith((task) =>
     {
         string[] result = task.Result;
         foreach(string taskname in result)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Result: " + taskname);
         }
     });

     t.Wait();
     Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: can u guide me how to routine name when completed. here we are executing 2 routine Task1 & Task2. so from the button click how could i show routine name like Task2() is completed. thanks

Comment: For WhenAll or WhenAny?

Comment: here you are running two task and i want when any task will be completed then task name will be return to its calling environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ContinueWith method for every task that will update the progress.

So...

```
foreach (var t in tasks)
{
   t.ContinueWith(Console.WriteLine("Hey I am done"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Pass in a callback function

```
public async Task DoOperationsInParallelAsync(Action<Task<int>> completed)
{
    var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(); 
    var tasks = new[] { DoOperation0(), DoOperation1(), DoOperation2() };

    var completedTasks = tasks.Select(x => x.ContinueWith(completed, uiScheduler)).ToArray();

    await Task.WhenAll(completedTasks);
}

private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await DoOperationsInParallelAsync(t => {
        Label1.Text = string.Format("Task finished with {0}", t.Result);
    });
}
```

2) The `Task` will run on the threadpool unless you specify it as long running or provide a `TaskScheduler`.

3) When only the first result matters (computation is redundant or time sensitive) such as grabbing stock prices from various providers mirroring similar data.

Comment: thanks for the reply. can u plzz post the full code that how to call DoOperationsInParallelAsync() where we can pass another function name reference as callback. and from callback how to show routine when completed like "DoOperation1() Done"

Comment: I added an example with a button and label.